# Enhance C# Enum in order to use Bitwise operation?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, enums

binary operation are *very useful* . this way I can do  `| ^ &` in order ro emit a new sequence.

However , sometimes there are `Enum`'s which doesnt have a `base 2` values attached to it 
(or value at all).

ie:

[image]

I would like to `Enhance || derive|| attach` values to the Enum ( if posssible ) to each entry.

so I will be able to do :

```
if (MyListItemType== Header |Footer ) ...
```

is it possible ? or is there any tricky work arounds ?

Comment: Do you mean on an existing enum that is not a `Flags` enum?

Comment: @oded yeah.  `sometimes there are Enum's which doesnt have a base 2... ` I dont see how flags can help me here.

Comment: This may sound weird but maybe you could make up a string of bits like `001010` and lookup the Enum and get your values

Comment: I have presented a solution using extension methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would like to Enhance || derive|| attach values to the Enum ( if posssible ) to each entry.

You can't do that (short of redefining the enum). But when it is in code you don't own, it's over. There can already exist code that relies on the numbering, changing the int values would break that code.

But this usually means the Enum was not intended to be a bit-set, so trying to use it as one probably isn't a good idea anyway.

It's a design decision for the creator of the code.

Look at your example list:

```
var item = ListItemType.Header | ListItemType.Footer | ListItemType.SelectedItem;
```

Can `item` really be a header, a footer and a selected item at the same time? This is a list of mutually-exclusive options.

Comment: +1 for... "*Can item really be a header, a footer and a selected item at the same time? This is a list of mutually-exclusive options.*"

Answer (score 5):

You want to use a [flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) enum:

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
    None = 0x0,
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4,
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40
}
class MyClass
{
    Days2 meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday;
}
```

Comment: I dont have control over the enum ! its inside a dll

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.

If an `Enum` was not marked with the `FlagsEnumeration` and/or has the correct bit mask values (as you put it - "doesn't have base2"), you can't use bitwise operations on it to get meaningful results.

Comment: The Flags attribute only affects ToString (and serialization). It is not necessary and certainly not sufficient to enable bit operations.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said it cannot be done but I will use a shortcut using Extension methods:

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        This,
        That,
        TheOther
    }

    public static class MyEnumeExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsAny(this MyEnum enumValue, params MyEnum[] values)
        {
            return values.Any((e) => e == enumValue);
        }
    }
```

So I can use:

```
myEnum.IsAny(This, That);
```

Which is **almost** what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: @RoyiNamir anytime mate. I had done something similar in the past in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Flag Enums:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
    None = 0x0,
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4,
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

You can then use bitwise operators on them.